# PouchDB / SQLite indexing crashes - needs to much memory on IOS

Tags: sqlite, cordova, indexeddb, web-sql, pouchdb

### Intro

I have build an IOS app with PouchDB and Ionic and Cordova stuff, but now i'm failing with the database and can't see a solution...

#### SQLite

[Sqlite plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) and the synchronization works great, but as soon i want to access the data PouchDB starts indexing which uses to much memory and my app crashes.
Here is a sampleApp with everything prepared for interested helpers to reproduce the crash
[SampleApp Github](https://github.com/mnewmedia/testApp)

#### WebSQL

In WebSQL I can't even sync the database, because I get the "QuotaExceededError" Error. Is there a way to ask for more space in an IOS uiwebview?

#### IndexedDB

Indexedb [isn't usable](https://gist.github.com/nolanlawson/08eb857c6b17a30c1b26), cause of too many bugs. And will it also not be better in IOS 9

So any ideas ideas or hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem of storage limits on iOS is indeed to use the SQLite Plugin. You can't exceed 50MB on WebSQL.

> Sqlite plugin and the synchronization works great, but as soon i want to access the data PouchDB starts indexing which uses to much memory and my app crashes.

Are you sure this is a bug with PouchDB and not with the SQLite Plugin? If it's a crash in Objective-C land, it belongs to the SQLite Plugin. If it's a crash in JavaScript land, it probably belongs to PouchDB.

Either way, if you could provide a test to reproduce, we would welcome a bug report on either the PouchDB Github issues page or the SQLite Plugin issues page. :)

Comment: That's what i thought with WebSQL. No, i tend more to a bug in SQLite. I will try to provide a sample where it fails tomorrow. Really really sad stuff with these db's on ios. 
Isn't it possible to dump an already indexed sqlite db and load it later similiar to your pouchdb-load plugin?

Comment: sample app with everything prepared and explained https://github.com/mnewmedia/testApp/

Answer (score 0):

About WebSQL, please consider this:
[PouchDB limits](http://pouchdb.com/faq.html#data_limits)

> Some versions of Safari have a bug where they only let you request additional storage once, so you'll need to request the desired space up-front. PouchDB allows you to do this using the size option.

Try allocating size upfront, and allocate your biggest expectations about the app. Hope that helps.

Good luck.